# Using Array.FindAll method to find subarray which meets criteria

Tags: arrays, vb.net, delegates, visual-studio-2005

I have an application in Visual Basic.Net and need to find all elements within an array which meet a certain condition.

```
Dim result As my_obj() = Array.FindAll(lstData, HasToBeSent)
```

Where the function `HasToBeSent` is defined like this:

```
Private Function HasToBeSent(ByVal cta As my_obj) As Boolean
    Return cta.IsSent
End Function
```

However this doesn't compile, it says I haven't specified an argument for the parameter `cta` in `Private Function HasToBeSent(ByVal cta As my_obj) As Boolean`

I am using Visual Studio 2005, therefore I have VB.Net 8.0. I am guessing the suggested answer is for higher versions of VB.Net. Because when I replace the previous code with

```
Dim result As my_obj() = Array.FindAll(lstData, Function(cta) HasToBeSent(cta))
```

It says: "expression expected"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why is this tagged with both vb6 and vb.net tags?

Comment: @soph: That is not VB6 code. It is vb.net. As such, I've removed the incorrect tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your `HasToBeSent` definition but add the `Shared` keyword to it to make it static (actually this is probably optional, but since this code doesn't rely on anything else in your class, it's probably a good design decision anyway).

```
Private Shared Function HasToBeSent(ByVal cta As my_obj) As Boolean
    Return cta.IsSent
End Function
```

And then in `Array.FindAll()`, give it the "address of" your function:

```
Array.FindAll(lstData, AddressOf HasToBeSent)
```

---

If you upgrade to a newer version of VB, then you can inline a delegate:

```
Array.FindAll(lstData, Function(cta) cta.IsSent)
```

To keep the `HasToBeSent` function, you can simply call that instead:

```
Array.FindAll(lstData, Function(cta) HasToBeSent(cta))
```

Comment: I just edited my question explaining why your solution doesn't work for me. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @Soph: I updated my answer. Hopefully we got it this time! :)

Comment: If LINQ is supported, I would go with this: `lstData.Where(Function(cta) cta.IsSent).ToArray`, just find it more intuitive.

Comment: @Neolisk: I would agree, but LINQ support didn't show up until VB.NET/VS 2008 :/

Comment: Almost! Now I get an error saying 'End Function must be preceded by the corresponding Function statement', and that the return statement can't be placed outside of a function. Why might this be?

Comment: It also shows an error saying "HasToBeSent is a type and can't be used as an expression"

Comment: @Soph: My bad. It's been a while since I've used 2005. I updated again  -- read it carefully, the change is very subtle.

Comment: @Cory EXCELLENT! Worked perfectly. Thanks! And yes.. I wouldn't be using 2005 if I had a choice :( That's the issue with old big systems.

Comment: @Soph: Glad I could help. Good luck with the rest of your project!